# How to allow users to view individual instances of a resource but not the index with CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'll try to be more clear than the title. I want users to be able to view all individual widgets which might be at the following URLs:

```
/widgets/2
/widgets/3
/widgets/45
```

But I don't want users to view the entire index:

```
/widgets
```

I know I can check this in the controller or even in the view for `index` and `show`, but I'm looking for a simpler way I can add this in the `Ability.rb` file:

```
can :read, Widget
```

Of course, that will allow users to view the index too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want users to be able to view all individual widgets .. 
>   but I don't want users to view the entire index

Use `:show`, not `:read`.

```
can :show, Widget
```

`:read` is an [alias](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Action-Aliases) for `[:show, :index]`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it has to be with cancan? cause if not you can do a before filter on the index action on the controller like this:

```
controller

before_filter :check_user,  :only => [:index]  

def index
  // code
end

def check_user
 if current_user.type==1
  redirect to root_url
 end
end
```

ok how about this with cancan

ability.rb

```
cannot :manage, Widget
```

controller

```
skip_authorize_resource :only => :show
```

Comment: I essentially did something similar to what you suggested, but I'm looking for how to do this with cancan